# PHP verify in db if exist duplicate

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I have this function:

```
public function addToFavoriteList($eventId, $userId)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO favorites (eventi_id, user_id) VALUES ($eventId, $userId)";
    $resultSet = $this->db->execute($sql);
    if (!$resultSet) {
        return array('error' => 'event exsist in favorites');
    }
    return array('error' => '');
}
```

and i want to check if the event alredy exist in db so i can show and error message for the user.
I write something like that but it doesen't work.

```
if (isset($_POST['addToFavourite'])) {
    $eventId = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['id']));
    $addToFavoriteOutcome = $eventMgr->addToFavoriteList($eventId, $userId);

    if (isset($addToFavoriteOutcome)) {
        $errorMessage = $addToFavoriteOutcome['error'];
    }
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Anyway by your own code, `$addToFavoriteOutcome` will be an _array_ (because that's what `addToFavoriteList` returns), so checking whether it's set makes no sense - your code ensure it's always created. Hint: Instead you might want to check whether the `error` property _within_ that array is blank or not...

Answer (score -3):

Try changing this:

```
if (isset($addToFavoriteOutcome)) {
    $errorMessage = $addToFavoriteOutcome['error'];
}
```

to this

```
if ($addToFavoriteOutcome) {
    $errorMessage = $addToFavoriteOutcome['error'];
}
```